# Cucumber, Java17: allowing step definition with lambda expression cucumber 7.1.1

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, java-17, scenarios

Trying to update the project with Java 17. It doesn't support cucumber-java8. If I try to upgrade cucumber- java to higher version like 7.1.1. I don't find that it allows step definition as lambda expression.

I tried few lower versions but it doesn't allow this feature above jdk 12

Comment: @ocos Cucumber Java8 is under consideration for deprecation but hasn't been deprecated yet.

Comment: @Prachi what is it that you actually observe happening and how would else someone reproduce your problem?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje My bad :(. I did not pay attention to deprecation status as I use  cucumber-java with kotlin.

Comment: @ocos no worries. I've updated the issue title to reflect the current status.

Comment: cucumber-java8 version 6.11.0 is supported for Java 17..any version higher then this is not compatible.

Comment: @Prachi what errors do you see with Cucumber that make you think this is the case? How can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example